# “Unable to find a live file system on the network” when PXE booting Ubuntu

Tags: pxe, tftp

I image bare metal servers to CentOS 7 and 8 all of the the time via network DHCP/TFTP using UEFI options, from a CentOS 7 PXE server. I'm looking to also build Ubuntu 20.04 servers.

I've followed the docs, extracted vmlinuz and initrd from the casper dir of the Ubuntu ISO and just placed them at the base tftpboot dir. Things hum along, the ISO downloads to the client, after it enters BusyBox and fires up initramfs, it completes loading the ISO, but then stops at "Unable to find a live file system on the network". The thing is, I'm able to navigate and find the ISO on the client, and I'm even able to mount it and see that all of the contents are there.

I've used different ISOs (Ubuntu desktop, for example). I've verified sha sums of the ISO.

Here's the grub.cfg that I'm using, paring everything back to isolate the issue.

```
timeout=30
timeout_style=menu

menuentry 'Ubuntu 20.04.2' {
  linuxefi /vmlinuz ip=dhcp url=http://10.10.10.1/ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso
  initrdefi /initrd
}

menuentry 'CentOS 7.8' {
  linuxefi /centos/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz ip=dhcp inst.repo=http://10.10.10.1:/centos
  initrdefi /centos/images/pxeboot/initrd.img
}
```

The CentOS install works just fine (/centos is the path to a dump of a CentOS ISO).

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: my grub config looks a little different than yours, but I am getting the same error - even after successful download of the iso and busybox fires up